# Pandas expand cell with list of dictionaries into rows with column for key each

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
     col1                                     col2       col3
0    "[{'key1':'val1'}, {'key1':'val2'}]"        a          g
1    "[{'key1':'val3'}, {'key1':'val4'}]"        b          h
2    "[{'key1':'val5'}, {'key1':'val6'}]"        c          i
```

and I want to process it so it ends up like this:

```
     col2       col3   key1
0    a          g      val1 
1    a          g      val2
2    b          h      val3
3    b          h      val4
4    c          i      val5
5    c          i      val6
```

This is slightly simplified. The dictionaries in col1 have many more columns and there are more than two other columns.

I've seen solution similar in other posts, but all of them are working under the assumption that col1 is a regular list. I'm not familiar enough with pandas to figure how to get that solution to fit my case. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Update: I found the solution

First, I take the string and turn it into a list of dictionaries:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].apply(json.loads)
```

Then I explode that so each dictionary has its own row:

```
res = df.explode('col1')
```

Then I create a column for each of the keys in the dictionary:

```
res[['key1','key2','key3']] = res['col1'].apply(lambda x: self._explode_dict(x))
```

Here is my _explode_dict(row) function. The purpose is to avoid errors from empty dictionaries going into pd.Series

```
if (isinstance(row, dict) and bool(row)):
   return pd.Series(row)
return pd.Series({
    'key1': '',
    'key2': '',
    'key3': '',
})
```

Comment: `df = df.explode('col1').reset_index(drop=True)`, then `df.col1 = df.col1.str.get('key1')`